# How to turn an X and Y coordinate into a single digit that correlates to its spot on a chart

Tags: python, arrays, coordinates

I'm creating a miniature game in python. My screen is an array that has 36 indexes (9 by 4). My issue is when I want to move an element on the screen, I get a separate X and Y coordinate. These do not correspond to the screen. If my coordinates are (4, 3), the index that needs to be changed is slot 12. If my coordinates are (1, 1) the index that should be changed is 27. I can't think of a piece of logic I could use to calculate this automatically.

This is the chart:
[image: chart]

I'm using to visualize the index's of the chart. Bottom left is 1, 1. Top right is 9, 4.

This is the array in my code.

```
screen = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-" "\n",
          "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "\n",
          "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "\n",
          "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "\n"]
```

If I want to have my "character" at the coordinates (4, 2) for example, how would I automate calculating the index that I change?

Comment: How about `9 * (4 - Y) + X - 1`?

Comment: If you need to do the opposite in your game, that can be done using the built-in [`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function (or manually of course).